# Design a specific algorithm for a nxn array implemented on O(nlogn)

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

The problem:
Suppose that each row of an n×n array A consists of 1’s and 0’s such that, in any row of A, all the 1’s come before any 0’s in that row. Assuming A is already in memory, describe a method running in O(nlogn) time (not O(n2) time!) for counting the number of 1’s in A.

My experience: I have done it for O(n) but I dont know how can I achieve it with O(nlogN)
I would appreciate any help !

Comment: How _have_ you done it in O(n)? (Or did you mean O(n²)?)

Comment: This is not a thread and you can delete your question after you vandalized it yourself.

Comment: You should not just delete your question as soon as you got your answer!

Comment: Stack Overflow is almost *never* solely for the person asking the question. It's meant to be a repository for useful questions and answers for everybody in the future as well. Please do not ask question then replace the text with rubbish and delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that each individual row consists of all `1`s followed by all `0`s:

```
1111111000
```

You can use a binary search to find the transition point (the last `1` in the row). The way this works is to set low and high to the ends and check the middle.

If you are at the transition point, you're done. Otherwise, if you're in the `1`s, set low to one after the midpoint. Otherwise, you're in the `0`s, so set high to one before the midpoint.

That would go something like (pseudo-code, with some optimisations):

```
def countOnes(row):
    # Special cases first, , empty, all 0s, or all 1s.

    if row.length == 0: return 0
    if row[0] == "0": return 0
    if row[row.length - 1] == 1: return row.length

    # At this point, there must be at least one of each value,
    # so length >= 2. That means you're guaranteed to find a
    # transition point.

    lo = 0
    hi = row.length - 1
    while true:
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2
        if row[mid] == 1 and row[mid+1] == 0:
            return mid + 1
        if row[mid] == 1:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid - 1
```

Since a binary search for a single row is `O(logN)` and you need to do that for `N` rows, the resultant algorithm is `O(NlogN)`.

---

For a more *concrete* example, see the following complete Python program, which generates a mostly random matrix then uses the `O(N)` method and the `O(logN)` method (the former as confirmation) of counting the ones in each row:

```
import random

def slow_count(items):
    count = 0
    for item in items:
        if item == 0:
            break
        count += 1
    return count

def fast_count(items):
    # Special cases first, no 1s or all 1s.

    if len(items) == 0: return 0
    if items[0] == 0: return 0
    if items[len(items) - 1] == 1: return len(items)

    # At this point, there must be at least one of each value,
    # so length >= 2. That means you're guaranteed to find a
    # transition point.

    lo = 0
    hi = len(items) - 1
    while True:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if items[mid] == 1 and items[mid+1] == 0:
            return mid + 1
        if items[mid] == 1:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid - 1

# Ensure test data has rows with all zeros and all ones.

N = 20
matrix = [[1] * N, [0] * N]

# Populate other rows randomly.

random.seed()
for _ in range(N - 2):
    numOnes = random.randint(0, N)
    matrix.append([1] * numOnes + [0] * (N - numOnes))

# Print rows and counts using slow-proven and fast method.

for row in matrix:
    print(row, slow_count(row), fast_count(row))
```

The `fast_count` function is the equivalent of what I've provided in this answer.

A sample run is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 20 20
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 0 0
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 5 5
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 15 15
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 10 10
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1 1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 11 11
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 12 12
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 11 11
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1 1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 6 6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] 16 16
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 14 14
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 11 11
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 9 9
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 13 13
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 1 1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 4 4
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 6 6
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] 19 19
```